# How can Stream this code?

Tags: java, java-stream

How can make this 'for' with Stream? I really don't know how and will be thankful if someone help me

```
public <C extends Collection<?>> int save(C items) {
        log.info("Collection entering for save in the DB :_" + items.getClass() + " with size :_" + items.size());
        int rowsAffected = 0;
    if (!items.isEmpty()) {
        try (Connection connection = DBConnectionManager.getConnection()) {
            for (Object item : items) {
                String query = queryBuilder(item);
                try {
                    if (Model.class.isAssignableFrom(item.getClass())) {
                        PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(query);
                        stmt = fillStatement(item, stmt);
                        rowsAffected += stmt.executeUpdate();
                    } else {
                        log.info("Item _:" + item.getClass().getSimpleName()
                                 + "...");
                    }
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    log.error(e);
                }
            }
            return rowsAffected;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            log.error(e);
        }
 }
```

Comment: I think your code is fine like this, I don't see any reason why you want to use stream here!

Comment: Yeah I think same, but I have repository which is said, this for you must make with Stream

Answer (score 4):

After seeing your code I don't really think that `Streams` would make it any more readable, but see this snippet, which simplifies your method:

```
 public int save(Collection<? extends Model> items) {
    log.info("Collection entering for save in the DB :_" + items.getClass() + " with size :_" + items.size());
    if (items.isEmpty()) {
        return 0;
    } 
    int rowsAffected = 0;
    try (Connection connection = DBConnectionManager.getConnection()) {
        for (Model item : items) {
            String query = queryBuilder(item);
            try(PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(query),
                stmt = fillStatement(item, stmt)) {
                rowsAffected += stmt.executeUpdate();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                log.error(e);
            }
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        log.error(e);
    }
    return rowsAffected;
}
```

## The changes:

1. No need to use generics, nothing is done with parameter `C`
2. No need for the `Model.class.isAssignableFrom` just accept models only. It would not make sense to "save" a `collection` of half Models and half other stuff. Seperate them before that.
3. Closed the prepared statements too
4. Put the `return` statement at the end
5. Return directly `0` if `items` are empty

## If you still want to use streams:

As you've already outsourced the creation of the query `String` and the filling of the `PreparedStatement` you could also extract that part into another method, which then could be used in a `Stream`:

```
private int saveItem(Model item, Connection connection){
    String query = queryBuilder(item);
    try(PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(query),
        stmt = fillStatement(item, stmt)) {
        return stmt.executeUpdate();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        log.error(e);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Which then can be *streamed*:

```
rowsAffected = items.stream()                     // Stream<Model>
    .mapToInt(item -> saveItem(item, connection)) // IntStream
    .sum();                                       // int
```

Comment: very good answer, however, we dont know if OP just wants to try streams or maybe has the explicit task to make it a stream, because in these cases, it kinda missed the point. upvoted anyway, because in every other practical case, this was very helpful.

Comment: @Instinct I added a part which uses the `Stream` API

Comment: @Instinct being forced to use streams will never lead to a useful solution. Streams can highly overcomplicate things if used incorrectly

Comment: i agree, but to use it correctly, you gotta learn it at some point, and this might be it, according to the comments from OP below his question.

Comment: @Lino I looked at the code and thought, way too much to dig into, but you... plus one!